# SQL Server , inserting existing rows into the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, insert

I have a table say Table A

[image]

- Col A is the primary key (identity).
- Col b is a foreign key from some other table.

Now, for example I want to select the rows where colB = 2 , and insert the rows back into the table again but with a different value of col B say 5 . This can be done easily. Next once the rows are inserted again, I need to find the relation between the copies, especially.

Say new rows are inserted with primary key 6,7,8. Now I want to check which parent row (row with primary key value 1/2/3) has the same data as row with primary key 6. Similarly, I need to find relative for the row with primary key 7, 8. One way is to do the insert one row at a time so that we can say that row with primary key 1 is the copy of row with primary key 6. Another way to do is to join all the columns. I am trying to avoid all these to see if there is any easy solution possible.

Comment: Remove the verbose text and show us desired output.

Comment: i think all you get is join all the columns, if you just want to check, you can easily use group to see if it have a copy but when you want to find out their ColA join is the best i can do

Comment: Remove the verbose text and show us the desired output and complete the following statement by a statement about A, B, C, D, E, F & G:  Row <A,B,C,D,E,F,G> is in the desired output if and only if ...". PS What problem statement were you given?

Comment: If you are updating the PK then the rest of multiple rows could be the same and it doesn't make sense to talk about the single DELETEd key value of an INSERTED row.

Comment: Are you picking the new key values or are they auto-incremented? What exactly is all the input and all the output? Please be clearer about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to get last primary key inserted value on your table. If another process could be modifying the table then do your update & query in one transaction.